# defining location of local HTML files

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Silly question that am embarrassed to ask, but cannot figure it out.

Adding a local html is easy, but as I will have a few different pages (scenes), I need each html page to have its own directory.

I am struggling how to define the location (directory) of the html files to be used.

Here is the code using:

```
    let filePath = ("html_shark" as  NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("sharks.html")
    let url:NSURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath:filePath)
    let request:NSURLRequest=NSURLRequest(URL:url)
    myWebView!.loadRequest(request)
```

The two folders that will be used are the

html_shark @ sharks.html and 
HTML_turtlesCon @turtles.html

Comment: Your question is not clear, give me some example.

Comment: I have the code to create a local html page into a webview.  If I run "sharks.html" with all of the files (css et all) in the xcode directory of the app, it runs fine.  However, i have will three different controllers executing 3 different html pages.  Each have their own, different directory.  I don't understand how to define the directory location where the html file is located on the view controller.  Does this help?

Comment: The css/js/image files located on the same directory of the HTML file, or subdirectories? Could you please post a screenshot of the HTML files struction in Xcode?

Comment: Piles of big screenshots don't really make for an acceptable Stack Overflow question.  Paste everything in plain text.  Not only does this condense the information in a smaller space (so it can more easily be viewed all at once), it improves the search-ability of the question.

Comment: I was in a chat with someone and he needed to see screen shots.  As I only have (had) 31 points, I could not post images inside the chat room.  I had to post here for him to see them.  I understand and agree with you, but i had no choice in order to solve the issue.  Please reinstate the up vote.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure you have real folders and not groups only. if so something like

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("htmlpage2", ofType: "htm", inDirectory:"sub")
// use path to create nsurl for nsurlrequest
```

Comment: I tried yours and am getting the fatal error due to nil.  It does not seem to find the html file.  I will add a screen shot to my original post to show you.  I really thought this would be easy....hmmmm.

Comment: you have the myfiles subdir

Comment: for subsubs use ```inDirectory:"sub/subsub"```

Comment: I tried that.  I also tried moving the folder to the root level and still did not work.  Is there something else wrong with the code as the variable htmlFile always in "nil".  It is possible something else is at error and not the path?

Comment: From which context do you execute this. The files are in Test if I get the Screenshot right?

Comment: If i understand your queston correctly, yes all of the files are visible above in the directory "EduConIntegrationTest".  Not sure what you mean by which context do you execute this.

Comment: What is the path of the HTML relative to Bundle root and how do you build the URL. And: are these real folders and not groups only

Comment: Maybe you can use the others methods in Bundle e.g. to list existing paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107482/discussion-between-david-sanford-and-christian-dietrich).

Answer (score 0):

`[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"foo/bar.html"]` will be `file:///foo/bar.html`, it means a file URL which located `/foo/bar.html` on the device file system, `/` is not the root directory of your app's bundle path.
You can get the root path for your app with `NSBundle` class. e.g. `[NSBundle mainBundle].bundlePath`.

For your issue, if your `html_shark` `HTML_turtlesCon` directories show yellow icon color in Xcode, use this code below:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourceURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"sharks.html"];
```

and if directories contains html files show blue icon color in Xcode, use:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourceURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"html_shark/sharks.html"];
```

Swift code:

```
let url:NSURL = (NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sharks.html"))!
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
```

Comment: Elf, is this Obj C?  I get many errors when trying this, plus the ; at the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry I don't known much about Swift, in Swift, code should be `let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("sharks.html")`